# What Cygwin Package Allows Me To Debug Python Code?

Tags: python, debugging, cygwin

There were other similar questions but none of them were exactly what I'm looking for, and ones that did didn't have any answers.

I'm looking for a python debugger for Cygwin. For example, I have the gdb debugger for debugging C++. I found something called pdb, but in the cygwin package list I couldn't find it. I looked at every package in the Python section and the debug section, but I couldn't find anything. If any, what package can I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The python debugger is part of the various python packages
https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html

```
 $ cygcheck -l python37 | grep  pdb.py
/usr/lib/python3.7/pdb.py
```

or also

```
$ cygcheck -p pdb.py
Found 35 matches for pdb.py
python2-test-2.7.14-1 - python2-test: Python 2 tests
python2-2.7.14-1 - python2: Python 2 language interpreter
python27-test-2.7.15-1 - python27-test: Python 2 tests
python27-test-2.7.16-1 - python27-test: Python 2 tests
python27-2.7.15-1 - python27: Python 2 language interpreter
python27-2.7.16-1 - python27: Python 2 language interpreter
python3-test-3.6.3-1 - python3-test: Py3K tests
python3-test-3.6.4-1 - python3-test: Py3K tests
python3-3.6.3-1 - python3: Py3K language interpreter
python3-3.6.4-1 - python3: Py3K language interpreter
python35-test-3.5.6-1 - python35-test: Py3K tests
python35-test-3.5.7-1 - python35-test: Py3K tests
python35-test-3.5.7-2 - python35-test: Py3K tests
python35-3.5.6-1 - python35: Py3K language interpreter
python35-3.5.7-1 - python35: Py3K language interpreter
python35-3.5.7-2 - python35: Py3K language interpreter
python36-test-3.6.8-1 - python36-test: Py3K tests
python36-test-3.6.9-1 - python36-test: Py3K tests
python36-3.6.8-1 - python36: Py3K language interpreter
python36-3.6.9-1 - python36: Py3K language interpreter
python37-test-3.7.3-1 - python37-test: Py3K tests
python37-test-3.7.4-1 - python37-test: Py3K tests
python37-test-3.7.7-1 - python37-test: Py3K tests
python37-3.7.3-1 - python37: Py3K language interpreter
python37-3.7.4-1 - python37: Py3K language interpreter
python37-3.7.7-1 - python37: Py3K language interpreter
python38-test-3.8.0-0.4.b2 - python38-test: Py3K tests
python38-test-3.8.0-0.5.b4 - python38-test: Py3K tests
python38-test-3.8.2-1 - python38-test: Py3K tests
python38-3.8.0-0.4.b2 - python38: Py3K language interpreter
python38-3.8.0-0.5.b4 - python38: Py3K language interpreter
python38-3.8.2-1 - python38: Py3K language interpreter
....
```